# How to remove spam page from wp-include?

Tags: wordpress

The problem is someone hacked our client Wordpress website and put some spam page in WP-include. So we want to remove spam page from WP-include by Wordpress instead of by sever because our client don’t have sever details of that website. So how can we do, provide us some easier way to remove spam page.

Answer (score 0):

That is a tricky question, as far as I know.. Wordpress won't allow you to modify wp_include.php from wordpress.com. Allowing you to modify the file will give a high risk that the website will malfunction cutting the connection to wordpress.com

Your client should have the server details if they really own that website